# Empty rows in confusion matrix of a neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, seaborn, confusion-matrix

Could you please say what's wrong with my confusion matrix? Two rows are empty, however, when I print out the confusion matrix (without plotting) the rows are not empty. That is the code that I use:

```
num_classes = 2
confusion_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted_labels)

# Calculate total counts for each label
label_counts = np.sum(confusion_mat, axis=1)

# Create a new confusion matrix with an additional row and column for label counts
confusion_mat_with_counts = np.zeros((num_classes + 1, num_classes + 1), dtype=np.int64)
confusion_mat_with_counts[:num_classes, :num_classes] = confusion_mat
confusion_mat_with_counts[:num_classes, num_classes] = label_counts
confusion_mat_with_counts[num_classes, :num_classes] = np.sum(confusion_mat, axis=0)
confusion_mat_with_counts[num_classes, num_classes] = np.sum(confusion_mat)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.heatmap(confusion_mat_with_counts, annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", fmt="d", xticklabels=list(label_encoder.classes_) + ['Total'], yticklabels=list(label_encoder.classes_) + ['Total'], cbar=False)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
plt.xlabel("True Labels")
plt.ylabel("Predicted Labels")
plt.show()
```

I tried to simplify the code like this:

```
num_classes = 2
confusion_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted_labels)

sns.heatmap(confusion_mat, annot=True, cmap='Blues', fmt='g')

plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.ylabel('True Label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
plt.savefig('confusion_matrix.png')
plt.show()
```

The printed confusion matrix is:

```
[[ 28  23  51]
 [ 19 104 123]
 [ 47 127 174]]
```

But the problem is not resolved. The image shows the issue with the confusion matrix plot.
[image]

Comment: I could not replicate your error. What version of seaborn/numpy do you have, do you use the `confusion_matrix` from sklearn or tensorflow? (If not TF, why the TF label?)

Comment: I have numpy=1.23.5 and seaborn=0.12.2. I used the confusion matrix from sklearn.

Comment: I tested it with the same seaborn version, with the confusion matrix from sklearn and tensorflow, and inside a jupyter notebook, with plotting and saving as a file, and for me it works. Sorry to say that, but I have no idea why this looks so weird for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying! I guess that there is some incompatibility in my conda environment that causes this weird problem. But I dunno what to do and how to resolve it!

Comment: Did you try the same code in a fresh environment? You can set up one real quick, install the packages, and make your own `y_test, predicted_labels` with `y_pred = np.array(28*[0]+23*[1]+19*[0]+104*[1])`, `y_true = np.array((28+23)*[0]+(19+104)*[1])`. This gives you the labels for the current confusion matrix.

Comment: You need to update your seaborn: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3478